# LIBOR Market Model (LMM) - references

Tags: interest-rates, reference-request

Could you advice me where I can find the best mathematical description of **LIBOR Market Model** theory (except the references from the [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIBOR_market_model)). Is there any book/article/pdf file/web page/notes which you found particluarly useful when you studed this theory?

Thanks for sharing your experiance!

Comment: See the books by Shreve or Hull. They cover LIBOR modelling very well, although a simple google for either LIBOR modelling or introduction to fixed income markets should be enough.

Comment: You may have a look of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Pricing-Interest-Rate-Derivatives-Market/dp/0691089736) and [this book](https://www.amazon.com/SABR-LIBOR-Market-Model-Interest-Rate/dp/0470740051).

Comment: For what it's worth completely echo Gordon's recommendation on Rebonato, very well written particularly vis a vis calibration. In addition to which am a big fan of [Brigo and Mercurio](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783540221494) - a very lively text covering a vast swathe of fixed income in general which will stand you in good stead wherever your studies take you.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation points to give you +1...